# Zoom function almost complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

My co-worker almost finished this zoom function, but I can't figure out how to complete it. [Here is a jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/hfYDA/) The red dots are supposed to stay in the same location relative to the image as you move the slider on the right. Everything is great except the code in the $('.marker').each(function(){...}); I have tried many combinations, but can't seem to get the right logic for the zoom. Thanks!

Here is the JS:

```
$( "#sliderVertical" ).slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    value: 50,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#sliderValue" ).text( ui.value );
        var backImg = $('img');
        if (ui.value == 0) {
            ui.value = 0.1;
        }        
        var width = ui.value * 12;
        var height = width * .75;

        $('.marker').each(function(){
            var marginLeft = parseFloat($(this).css('margin-left')),
            totalWidth = parseFloat(backImg.css('width'));
            var newMarginLeft = null;

            var marginTop = parseFloat($(this).css('margin-top')),
            totalHeight = parseFloat(backImg.css('height'));
            var newMrginTop = null;

            console.log(totalHeight);

            //$(this).css({'margin-left': newMarginLeft + 'px', 'margin-top': newMrginTop + 'px'});
        });

        var marLeft =  0 - (width / 2);
        var marTop = 0 - (height / 2);

        backImg.css({'width': width + 'px', 'height': height + 'px', 'margin-left': marLeft + 'px', 'margin-top': marTop + 'px'});

    }
});
```

Comment: It is a fiendish puzzle indeed. Might I suggest adding the red dots as child elements of the bigger picture and using `position:relative`

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat I don't really see how that is gonna make it easier, but I guess it could help. I feel like the logic would remain largely the same though.

Comment: @watson If you set the current `img` as a background for a `div` and put your markers in there, once you have them positioned, if you resize the `div` with your slider, the markers should move to their proper spots without needing help from JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.marker').each(function(){
            var marginLeft = parseFloat($(this).css('margin-left')),
            totalWidth = parseFloat(backImg.css('width'));
            var newMarginLeft = marginLeft*width/totalWidth;

            var marginTop = parseFloat($(this).css('margin-top')),
            totalHeight = parseFloat(backImg.css('height'));
            var newMrginTop = marginTop*height/totalHeight;

            console.log(totalHeight);

            $(this).css({'margin-left': newMarginLeft + 'px', 'margin-top': newMrginTop + 'px'});
        });
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/hfYDA/1/)

Comment: I should note that this somehow breaks if you go all the way down to zoom 0. You can workaround this by only going down up to 1.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Just out of curiosity, how long did it take you to get it?

Comment: Not long. You basically had it figured out. I saw the commented out code that applies the margin on the markers and saw that `newMarginLeft` and `newMrginTop` haven't been set to anything. It was a matter of scaling. You knew the width of the image and its new width so it was just scaling the margin by that same factor.